# Capacitor as voltage source but why not as current source

Tags: capacitor

I have read from so many articles that capacitor acts as voltage source if it has some initial charge in it when connected to load. But why we consider capacitor as voltage source , why not consider as current source?

Comment: Actually, you can, if you think about applications that can be applied in ac. One of my fixes for old 110V radios was putting a capacitor in series to do the 10V voltage drop. But you had to size it correctly otherwise it would limit the current.

Comment: because voltage is the nice-looking linear measurement with caps, like current for inductors.

Comment: Because the energy is stored in electric field in a capacitor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***When we describe something as an (ideal) 'voltage source' or 'current source', we are really describing its behaviour when we connect it to a load.***

*In particular, we do **not** mean that a current source only supplies current and not voltage, or that a voltage source only supplies voltage and no current. Actually **both kinds of sources can supply voltage and current to a circuit**. This seems to be a surprisingly common misconception.*

For example, if we have a voltage source of e.g. 9 volts, and we connect it to a resistor, the voltage across the resistor will be 9 volts. On the other hand, the current through the resistor depends on the resistance according to the equation:
$$ I = \frac{9}{R}$$
if we change the resistance, the current will also change according to this equation, but the voltage across the resistor will remain at 9 volts. So **a voltage source supplies the same voltage across any load**.

If we connect a current source of 2A to the resistor instead, then the voltage across the resistor depends on the voltage according to the equation
$$
V = 2R
$$
but the current is now fixed at 2A. So **a current source supplies the same current across any load**.

For a capacitor charged to e.g. 5V, when we connect it to a resistor we find that the voltage across the resistor is 5V and the current through the resistor is:
$$ I = \frac{5}{R}$$
If we were to try this with different resistors, we would find that the voltage across the resistor would always be 5V but the current would change depending on the value of the resistance. This is the same behaviour as our ideal voltage source, so we say that the capacitor behaves as a voltage source.

Of course, in practice capacitors tend to discharge quickly and the voltage would then drop over time, so the discussion above only really applies to the instant of time immediately after you connect the circuit. However, even though the capacitor voltage drops with time as it is discharged, we still find that it supplies the same voltage regardless of the value of the resistor.

Comment: Thank you sir. I have clearly understand now why capacitor acts as voltage source instead of current source. So, it means capacitor never supply constant current for any resistance. Is it right ?

Comment: It means capacitor supply constant voltage for any resistance(even the resistance is in Megha ohms) for t = 0+ instant

Comment: Exactly correct - If the resistance was in the mega-Ohm range, we would still have the same voltage, but the current would be very small.

Answer (score 4):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXMZRw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Ideal components with ideal meters.*

An alternative approach to understanding is:

- An ideal capacitor can sustain a voltage indefinitely. (In practice its leakage resistance will discharge it.) It can't sustain a current indefinitely.
- An ideal inductor can sustain a current into a perfect short-circuit indefinitely. (In practice its internal resistance will dissipate the energy.) It can't sustain a voltage indefinitely.

Comment: My question is about the capacitor acting as voltage source when connected to a load, but you did not connect any load in the schematic.

Comment: You didn't reference any of the many sources mentioned in your question so it is difficult to guess the context. Generally when we talk about voltage sources we expect the voltage to remain fairly constant when a load is applied. Clearly this is not the case for a capacitor so I suspect the premise of your question is flawed. I hoped to illustrate that in contrast with an inductor it can, when lightly loaded with respect to time behave as a voltage source whereas the inductor behaves more like a current source.

Comment: Yeah it's ok. I got the answer for my question. The capacitor acts as voltage source only at particular instant of time, when sudden application of load is done across charged capacitor.

Comment: I don't think that's really a good answer (whichever one you're referring too) as at any instant it is also a current source. In any case it's likely to be of little value other than to think of capacitors as tending to maintain voltage across them and inductors tending to maintain current through them.

Comment: The first answer to this question given by JayMfleming is very satisfactory. Please read it.

Comment: You can check and understand the concept from simulation also. Here is the link http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-cap.html

Comment: It's OK. I know how they work and I design circuits, etc., over many, many years.

Answer (score 0):

Because a capacitor stores charge, and the total charge inside a capacitor is proportional to voltage. However, a current is drawn from the capacitor if the voltage is changing, making it both a voltage and a current source in that case.

Comment: To add to my comment, we know that C = Q/V, and i = C*dv/dt. If Voltage isn't changing (dv/dt = 0), then we don't have to worry about the current, making it only a voltage source, as it still contains a potential difference produced by the load.

Comment: This is incorrect. The fact that current is drawn from it when it is connected to a circuit, does not make it a current source (see my answer, where I have tried to make this clear). As an example, a battery is a voltage source and not a current source, but current flows from it when we connect it to a circuit.

Comment: Yes , current will be drawn from it. But the voltage source means the source which supply constant voltage to load. You connect any high resistance across the voltage source, you can see that the voltage across the load is always constant. The voltage source always maintains same voltage across load. Though the current is drawn from voltage source, it is not considered as current source, because maintaining constant voltage across the load is responsible for voltage source. So, the capacitor do this job for small instant of time( at t = 0+).

Comment: Hence capacitor consider as voltage source, but only at t = 0+ instant. After that it cannot maintain that voltage. Hence not consider as voltage source.

Answer (score 0):

Capacitance \$C\$ is defined by the relationship between current \$i\$, voltage \$v\$, and time \$t\$:

$$ i(t)=C{\mathrm d v(t) \over \mathrm d t} $$

Or perhaps for this explanation it's better to write it like so:

$$ {i(t) \over C} = {\mathrm d v(t) \over \mathrm d t} $$

As the capacitance approaches infinity, the current required to change the voltage across the capacitor approaches infinity. Or thinking of the capacitor as the source, it can supply or sink an infinite current without changing its voltage. This is precisely the definition of a voltage source.

We don't consider a capacitor a current source because the math doesn't work out that way. But this isn't the world being unfair to current sources. The electrical dual of capacitance is inductance \$L\$, which is the same equation but with voltage and current swapped:

$$ v(t)=L{\mathrm di(t) \over \mathrm dt} $$

Analogously, as the inductance approaches infinity an inductor becomes a thing which can have any voltage across it without changing the current through it: the definition of a current source.